# How to configure Devise to re-authenticate user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to re-authenticate a user when the session is to old and he/she is checking out an order.

When I use:

```
redirect_to "/users/sign_in"
```

I get:

```
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
```

in the console.

Is there a way to configure Devise to enable re-authentiction of users before critical actions?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not just `sign_out current_user` or `sign_out_and_redirect current_user`?

Comment: Yes, but I thought there might be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're considering to re-authenticate the user, with a certain session timeout. You can configure devise to use :timeoutable option.

1. Add :timeoutable devise attribute in User model.
2. Modify initialisers/devise.rb: Uncomment the

   ```
   config.timeout_in = 30.minutes
   ```

   You can set this to any session time you prefer.
3. Restart the server.

Cheers!!